# Mathematica 8 sometimes hangs up over a simple instruction - ask more and it may unhang

Tags: front-end

Lately Mathematica 8 seems to have an 'underload' buffer where the current instruction is not executed unless it is given a few more tasks to do. This is very weird. Sometimes it takes just one more instruction, sometimes three or more - to 'flush' the buffer. Sometimes it just hangs.

Comment: This is not something I have encountered before and your question is very colloquially written and not clear enough about what it actually means to support a diagnosis. Please give further details, such as a video of this behavior or code to reproduce it. (Preferably both.)

Comment: Thanks for the observations Oleksandr. This is indeed very strange behavior from a normally stable Mathematica 8. I don't even know what initiates the 'hangs' - but it is usually after a long session. When I find a simple instruction taking too long to execute - abort will not work, so instead I put some trivial calculations on the queue and of course they hang too, but sometimes they execute after a few seconds and that frees the prior instructions.

Comment: It sounds as if perhaps *MathLink* is broken. You could try reinstalling *Mathematica* and see if this resolves the issue. Or, reset the front end configuration by holding `Ctrl` and `Shift` while starting *Mathematica*. But this is simply a guess as your description really does not support any specific diagnosis. If your front end and kernel are running on two different computers then it is a completely different issue, for example, but you do not specify this.

Comment: I have reset the front end as recommended by Oleksandr and I will post any new results as they occur (or don't occur). Thanks again for the suggestion Oleksandr. If this fails I will try reinstalling Mathematica 8.

Comment: Unfortunately the front end still hangs up occasionally after I reset the front-end as recommended by Olexsandr so I may have to try the next level which is to reinstall Mathematica 8.